# The `JAX-RS` resource throwing org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ModelValidationException after Progard Obfuscation

Tags: spring-boot, maven, jax-rs, proguard, obfuscation

I am having a `Spring boot` `multi-module` `maven` project running with `Java8`. This below class is being used to determine which resources we should be registering for our Jersey set-up-

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@Component
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    @Autowired
    private AutowireCapableBeanFactory beanFactory;

    @PostConstruct
    public void initialize() {

        // We will just look for all the classes in our resources
        // package annotated with @Path

        Reflections reflections = new Reflections("org.example.resource");
        Set<Class<? extends Object>> resources =
                reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(Path.class);
        resources.forEach(r -> {
            log.debug("Registering resource " + r);
            register(beanFactory.getBean(r));
        });

        register(ConstraintViolationExceptionMapper.class);

    }

}
```

Whereas, the REST endpoint looks like below:

```
@Component
@Api(value = "/api/1/summary", description = "Manage Summary")
@Path("/api/1/summary")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class SummaryResource extends AbstractUpdatableDomainResource<Summary> {

@ApiOperation(value = "Create new summary", notes = "Create a new summary and return with its unique id", response = Summary.class)
    @POST

    @Override
    public User create(Summary newInstance) {
       
    }

}
```

Now, if I ran with `-dontobfuscate` then everything is working as excepted but when `obfuscate` it ends up with the following errors:

```
[http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[localhost].[/web-context-path] - org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog - Servlet.init() for servlet [org.example.JerseyConfig] threw exception
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ModelValidationException: Validation of the application resource model has failed during application initialization.
[[HINT] A HTTP GET method, public void org.example.resource.FDService.a(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest), returns a void type. It can be intentional and perfectly fine, but it is a little uncommon that GET method returns always "204 No Content".; source='ResourceMethod{httpMethod=GET, consumedTypes=[], producedTypes=[application/pdf], suspended=false, suspendTimeout=0, suspendTimeoutUnit=MILLISECONDS, invocable=Invocable{handler=ClassBasedMethodHandler{handlerClass=class org.example.resource.FDService, handlerConstructors=[org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.HandlerConstructor@508c06e3]}, definitionMethod=public void org.example.resource.FDService.a(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest), parameters=[Parameter [type=interface javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse, source=null, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=interface javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, source=null, defaultValue=null]], responseType=void}, nameBindings=[]}'
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:394)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.lambda$initialize$1(ApplicationHandler.java:316)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:298)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:256)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:282)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:335)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:178)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:370)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1122)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:777)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**So my question is, what makes it NOT run if the code obfuscates? Why does obfuscation break the application? How to ignore ModelValidationException? What needs to tell proguard to exclude to make it run?**

Comment: Have you read the [HINT] for the error message? Doesn't seem like it has anything to do with obfuscation.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha I agree with your point but this is true when I use `dontobfuscate `, it works absolutely fine. So I wonder if something wrong with obfuscating so they are not being recognized as valid endpoints, I guess.

Comment: Is the method a GET tha returns void?

Comment: @PaulSamsotha yeah, it was. I updated it and then it came up with a different [HINT] error message. My point here is that before I started `code masking` using `progurad` even it was working so after code obfuscation why it's giving these vulnerabilities reporting?

Comment: [Not ideal but a workaround to avoid failure](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ServerProperties.html#RESOURCE_VALIDATION_IGNORE_ERRORS)